# Using CAST in WHERE clause in MySQL Update Query

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables, a local table in MS Access and a remote MySQL table linked via ODBC. They have identical order numbers except they are stored as a **string** in the remote table and a **number** in the local table. I can't seem to find how to update the local table. This was my initial code which gave me a 'Type Mismatch' error.

```
UPDATE
    localTable LT, remoteTable RT
SET
    LT.user = RT.user
WHERE
    LT.orderID = RT.orderID
```

I've tried using CAST but that doesn't seem to work either...

```
UPDATE
    localTable LT, remoteTable RT
SET
    LT.user = RT.user
WHERE
    LT.orderID = CAST(RT.orderID AS INTEGER)
```

I can't change the tables themselves to make them both string/number. Probably really simple but I can't seem to find the answer when using WHERE in an UPDATE query. Any help would be greatly received - thanks!

Comment: Why do you tag `ms-access`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access SQL, use `Val`:

```sql
UPDATE
    localTable LT, remoteTable RT
SET
    LT.user = RT.user
WHERE
    LT.orderID = Val(RT.orderID)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked perfectly! Apparently I have to wait a few more minutes to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [JOIN instead of a where clause](https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/difference-between-where-and-on-in-sql/). Access allows joins in the UPDATE command. The string can be converted by using an Access conversion function like `CLng`, `CDbl` etc.

```sql
UPDATE
    localTable LT
    INNER JOIN remoteTable RT
        ON LT.orderID = CLng(RT.orderID)
SET
    LT.user = RT.user
```